Как скачать сайт metanit.com с помощью wget?
Пытался скачать сайт metanit.com с помощью wget(windows), на первый взгляд все работает хорошо, но как только в пути сайта появляется файл с расширением .php происходит следующее

Рис.1
И да, без расширения .html в конце пути такая же проблема
Команда была такова:
wget --page-requisites -k -p -E -e robots=off --mirror -r -l 6 --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" --no-check-certificate https://metanit.com/
К слову, вот что должно быть вместо рисунка 1:

Рис.2

файлы с расширением php рассчитаны на интерпретатор php. На сервере перед выдачей страницы такие файлы выступают в качестве шаблона для сборки готовых страниц. Вы можете скачать php-интерпретатор для командной строки с официального сайта и запустить его например так: php general.php.html > general.html. Полученная страница будет соответствовать вашим ожиданиям

@Lebchik по вашей же логике сервер будет выдавать не php-код, а готовую страницу, которую wget и скачает, соответственно пытаться запустить готовую страницу командой php нет никакого смысла

А вообще дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1592503

@andreymal я попробовал повторить -- сайт действительно среди файлов html выдаёт также некоторые файлы php под видом .php.html. Странно, конечно )
